# How to Make Efficient Google-App-Engine Schema with Lots of BooleanPropertys

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, schema

I'm building a GAE app that has objects with a lot of boolean properties. I want to be able to search through those properties making a query like (in psuedo-sql) "get items where X1=True, X2=False, X3=False and let X4 through X7 be either true or false".

I have a model similar to the one shown below:

```
class JobModel(BaseModel):
  job_name      = db.StringProperty();
  part_time     = db.BooleanProperty();
  has_401k      = db.BooleanProperty();
  has_health_in = db.BooleanProperty();
  has_childcare = db.BooleanProperty();
  has_edu_reim  = db.BooleanProperty();
```

The problem is that GAE requires an index for every possible way of searching these booleans. So if you have 5 boolean properties you will need 32 different indexes. If you have 20 boolean properties (in my actual case) you need over a million indexes!

There must be a better way to setup this datastore schema, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a good opportunity for a StringListProperty.

Set membership is a strength of the ListProperty.

You would need to provide a way to update and marshal the list but it could be efficient for your needs.

**db.StringListProperty**

```
has = ['401k:T', 'health_in:F', 'has_childcare:T']
```

**GQL Where Clause**

```
"WHERE has = '401k:T' and has = 'health_in:F'"
```

ListProperties require some effort to understand their strengths and application.

[GAE datastore list property serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553273/gae-datastore-list-property-serialization)

Comment: That worked well and fixed the O(2^N) index problem, where N=number of properties to search. However your solution still requires O(N) indexes. No way to get around O(N) indexes, right?

Comment: The idea is to encode all of your properties into one listproperty, so that it is one index.  You do not want the "exploding index" problem. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes

Comment: I think I understand this "exploding index" problem. But by putting everything into one property, your code and data models turn into cludge.